# How do I display a stacked font-awesome icon above my section title in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

In the picture below, there is text shown as "stacked font-awesome icon". This is where I would like to display the stacked font-awesome icon. Specifically, I would like to display a font-awesome icon inside a square outline (i.e. font-awesome icon) and be able to resize it as I wish. The stacked icons are for a section on my website and will be displayed above the title.

Intended Result: https://postimg.org/image/3mkiestwf/

```
    <p align="center">One day I was walking in a forest. I sat down to catch my breath. I saw a spider and it startled me. I continued walking and saw a river. It began to rain. I did not have my rain boots on. I started to get wet so I hid under a tree. When the rain stopped, I began to walk home.</p>

        <div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        <ul style="float: right;">
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   List Item 1</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   List Item 2</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   List Item 3</li>
        </ul>

        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   List Item 4</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   List Item 5</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-check"></i>   List Item 6</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlxeY.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML:

```
<div class="icon">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-rocket fa-stack-1x"></i>
  </span>
</div>
... the rest of your content ...
```

CSS:

```
.icon {
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3fnLz9d/11/

Comment: Thanks for your response Beno. I did not get the result I wanted. The icon did not appear above the title. Please see the screenshot. I use a content management system. i.e. Joomla    [link]https://s11.postimg.org/5h7qo94b7/homepage.jpg)

Comment: It's hard to figure it out without seeing all the code. Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: I could not repro the issue on multiple attempts on jsfiddle but the issue persists on my website. See jsfiddle please. [link] https://jsfiddle.net/n3fnLz9d/9/)

Comment: Ok, i have updated you jsfiddle - i just needed to add the css reference to font awesome. The problem is the `<br>` tags inside the font awesome stack div. You can see the result on the jsfiddle link in the answer

Comment: Thanks again Beno. I tried your code but this is not exactly what I wanted (as per my question). The icons are below my title. My expected result is to have it above the title. If not too much trouble, can you please move the stacked font-awesome icon above the section title? Is there a css I can apply for this?

Comment: It didn't work. The stacked font-awesome icon is still between the section title and paragraph. The section title is part of the content management system i.e. Joomla. I enter text inside a textbox, and the title is displayed. How do I move the font-awesome icon above the section title so that it is centered and few spaces between the title?